# About regular representation and the irreducible representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am now learning group theory using Sadri Hassani's book "mathematical physics."
In the book, the author introduces the orthogonality condition for the unitary representation, which reads as follows
$$\sum_\alpha^{\rho}\chi^{(\alpha)}(x)\chi^{(\alpha)*}(y)=\frac{|G|}{|K_x^G|}\delta(K_x^G,K_y^G)$$
where $\chi^{(\alpha)}(x)$ is a character of irreducible representation of $x\in G$ and $K_x^G$ is the conjugacy group where $x\in G$ resides in.

What makes me confusing is the author's using $\sum{n_{\alpha}\chi^{(\alpha)}}_l=|G|\delta_{l1}$, which holds only for regular representations. ($i$ is the conjugacy class index, and 1 is the conjugacy class of identity).
The author even uses $\sum{n_{\alpha}\chi^{(\alpha)}}_l=|G|\delta_{l1}$ to the operators in QM, which is has the Hilbert space as a carrier space.

It seems if I assume the all inequivalent irreducible representation of whatever representation of group G is equivalent to some inequivalent irreducible representation of regular representation of group G, the problem can get resolved. But I am not sure if it is right and how to show it is right.

I don't know how to show that for any irreducible representation $T_i:G\rightarrow GL(W_i),\ W_i\subset V$ there always exists an isomorphism $f: W_i\rightarrow A_i$ such that $T_i'=f\circ T_i\circ f^{-1}$, where $T_i':G\rightarrow GL(A_i),\ A_i\subset A$ is the irreducible representation of a regular representation.

Could someone please help me understand this?

Comment: If $W$ is any irrep and $\Bbb CG$ is the regular rep then $\dim_G\hom(\Bbb CG,V)$ counts the multiplicity of $W$ in the regular rep, but also $\hom(\Bbb CG,V)\cong V$ as vector spaces since a morphism $\Bbb CG\to V$ is determined by $1\mapsto v$ (with $v\in V$ arbitrary). Thus, not only does every irrep $V$ appear as a subrep of the regular rep, its multiplicity is the same as its dimension.

Comment: Thank you. It turned out that the author did not use those identities in the representations whose carrier is the Hilbert space, but your comment was really helpful in understanding other logic in the book.